Error in scipy curve_fit when using absolute_sigma
I have this code:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def lin_func(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b

a = 0.005/4
b = 10000/4
N = 10000

position_list = np.array([-100,-50,-20,0,20,50,100]) 

def get_params(N):
    counts_list = np.zeros(len(position_list))
    for i in range(len(position_list)):
        position_0 = position_list[i]
        counts = 0
        for j in range(N):
            position = np.random.normal(position_0,10)
            p = 0.5+a+b*position*10**(-6) 
            counts = counts + np.sum(np.random.binomial(1000, p, 1)) 
        counts_list[i] = counts
    print(np.sqrt(counts_list))
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(lin_func, position_list*10**(-6), counts_list, absolute_sigma = np.sqrt(counts_list))
    return popt[1]/(N*1000)

K = 100
params_list = np.zeros(K)
for i in range(K):
    params_list[i] = get_params(N)-0.5
    print(params_list[i])

When I run it, it runs ok for a while, but then it displays this error:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

This only happens if I add absolute_sigma = np.sqrt(counts_list) to the function call, however if I print counts_list I don't see anything wrong with the number, just before the error pops up (they seem similar to the values printed when the function call works just fine). I am not sure how to debug this.
This is the full error message:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 4
      2 params_list = np.zeros(K)
      3 for i in range(K):
----> 4     params_list[i] = get_params(N)-0.5
      5     print(params_list[i])

Cell In[9], line 13, in get_params(N)
     11     counts_list[i] = counts
     12 print(np.sqrt(counts_list))
---> 13 popt, pcov = curve_fit(lin_func, position_list*10**(-6), counts_list, absolute_sigma = np.sqrt(counts_list))
     14 return popt[1]/(N*1000)

File ~/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py:897, in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, full_output, **kwargs)
    895     pcov.fill(inf)
    896     warn_cov = True
--> 897 elif not absolute_sigma:
    898     if ysize > p0.size:
    899         s_sq = cost / (ysize - p0.size)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()


The full error - which you should show - tells you the python package file in which this comes up. You can find this file on your computer and it will tell you what is going on at this point.

@lastchance I put the full error message in the original post, but I still don't know what to do with that information.

It’s meant to be True or False (see Warren Weckesser’s answer). However, if you show more of the code from the Python package it is a surprise to me that it didn’t get to that elif statement before, suggesting there may be more problems with your code than this.

I am actually confused now as to why it is working for a while before displaying the error (thanks for pointing out the True/False issue, I missed that). The code works fine without absolute_sigma. I actually solved the issue with pen and paper for smaller numbers and I am getting the same result as the code.

Take another look at the curve_fit docstring.  absolute_sigma is expected to be a boolean parameter.  I suspect you meant to set the parameter sigma, not absolute_sigma.

Thanks! I missed that. Why is it working for a while tho? Also the number of times it works in that K-loop seems to vary also. Also, what does that error mean. It wasn't clear at all to me that I am passing the wrong object from the displayed error.

@AlexMarshall "Also, what does that error mean." Here is a general explanation of what this error means. In this specific case, the cause is what Warren mentions: absolute_sigma can't be an array, because the code in curve_fit assumes it is a boolean. I do agree that this is a confusing error message - if you'd like to see it improved, I would suggest filing an issue upstream to ask the SciPy devs to fix it.

@AlexMarshall "Why is it working for a while tho? Also the number of times it works in that K-loop seems to vary also." Looking at the source code, absolute_sigma is only evaluated if the covariance is not indeterminate. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.14.1/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py#L1045
